# RawDisk VMDK has a virtual size of zero

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning, vmdk

Using VirtualBox on Linux, I have a virtual machine set up to boot from my physical Windows 7 partition on `/dev/sdb1` through a VMDK file that I had created using `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk` and worked fine. While upgrading to Windows 10, I reparitioned the drive, making it necessary to regenerate the VMDK file. However, I have upgraded to VirtualBox 7.0.2, and the command now [seems to be](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) `VBoxManage createmedium disk`:

```
VBoxManage createmedium disk \
--filename disk-passthrough.vmdk \
--format=VMDK --variant RawDisk \
--property RawDrive=/dev/sdb \
--property Partitions=1
```

My issue is that the resulting VMDK file advertises a "virtual size" of zero, and is seen as such by the guest live installer, which cannot proceed. The "actual size" is the size of the whole drive, which I think is expected. The "size" slider in the Virtual Media Manager GUI does not work, and I can't find anything in the vmdk file itself.

The disk as listed by `VBoxManage list hostdrives`:

```
Drive:       /dev/sdb
Model:       "ATA WDC WD10EZEX-00B"
UUID:        badea8e5-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Size:        931.5GiB
Sector Size: 512 bytes
Scheme:      MBR
Partitions:                   First         Last
##  Type  Size      Start     Cyl/Head/Sec  Cyl/Head/Sec Active
 1   07   124.3GiB    1.0MiB     0/ 32/33   1023/254/63   yes   IFS
 5   07   807.1GiB  124.3GiB  1023/254/63   1023/254/63   no   IFS
```

The generated VMDK file:

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
CID=0a12cf60
parentCID=ffffffff
createType="partitionedDevice"

# Extent description
RW 2048 FLAT "disk-passthrough-pt.vmdk" 0
RW 260724736 FLAT "/dev/sdb" 2048
RW 2048 ZERO 
RW 2048 FLAT "disk-passthrough-pt.vmdk" 2048
RW 1692792832 ZERO 
RW 36028795065440256 ZERO 

# The disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.virtualHWVersion = "4"
ddb.adapterType="ide"
ddb.uuid.image="0574bafb-3aae-48c9-8fad-410505bb7d46"
ddb.uuid.parent="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.uuid.modification="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.uuid.parentmodification="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
```

The virtual disk as listed by `VBoxManage list hdds`:

```
UUID:           0574bafb-3aae-48c9-8fad-410505bb7d46
Parent UUID:    base
State:          created
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       /home/quentin/VirtualBox VMs/win10/disk-passthrough.vmdk
Storage format: VMDK
Capacity:       0 MBytes
Encryption:     disabled
```

Backup of the previous VMDK file (note that partition #2 has been deleted, and partition #1 extended):

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
CID=35130ae5
parentCID=ffffffff
createType="partitionedDevice"

# Extent description
RW 63 FLAT "disk-passthrough-pt.vmdk" 0
RW 1985 ZERO 
RW 250241024 FLAT "/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD10EZEX-00BN5A0_WD-WCC3F3675084-part1" 0
RW 10485760 FLAT "/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD10EZEX-00BN5A0_WD-WCC3F3675084-part3" 0
RW 63 FLAT "disk-passthrough-pt.vmdk" 63
RW 1985 ZERO 
RW 1692792832 FLAT "/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD10EZEX-00BN5A0_WD-WCC3F3675084-part5" 0
RW 1456 ZERO 

# The disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.virtualHWVersion = "4"
ddb.adapterType="ide"
ddb.geometry.cylinders="16383"
ddb.geometry.heads="16"
ddb.geometry.sectors="63"
ddb.uuid.image="13b50da8-f9c6-4f14-b005-5da933b3693a"
ddb.uuid.parent="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.uuid.modification="bb23de78-f57b-4c71-b187-81aaf21542a5"
ddb.uuid.parentmodification="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.geometry.biosCylinders="1024"
ddb.geometry.biosHeads="255"
ddb.geometry.biosSectors="63"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its a known issue that is being addressed https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/21125

Comment: Great! Somehow I hadn't come across that thread.